# Get last week of year based on current week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am trying to update a table based on the avg currency conversion rate. What i want to do is for current week select avg conversion rate from previous week and apply conversion.

```
UPDATE cost,
(
SELECT yearweek(c.currency_date) w,
c.currency _currency, AVG(c.rate) rate
FROM currency c
GROUP BY w,_currency) src 

SET
cost.cost = cost.cost/src.rate,
cost.currencyid = 'EUR'
WHERE YEARWEEK(cost.occured_at)= ??

 and cost.currencyid = _currency
```

but i dont know how to get avg rate for last week based on current week

Comment: It would be helpful to see your table structure. Do you want the week number of the previous week? Do you want all of the days in the previous week? There's currently not quite enough information to provide an informed answer.

Comment: i have table currency with date,currency code, and rate and i want to calculate avg rate base on week and apply this rate to cost table. Cost table also have currency code,date and total cost. the cost is the column where i want converions

Comment: By *last week*, do you mean the seven days ending today, the seven days ending yesterday, the seven days ending the previous Monday, the seven days ending the previous Sunday, or something else?

Comment: i mean if today is week ten then take rate for week 9

Comment: If you asking what to replace the `??` with, then try `YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(NOW(), 1 WEEK))`